# The Kendo Datepicker change event does not fire until I click outside of Datepicker control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-datepicker

I have the following ASP.NET MVC form with a `datepicker` change event:

```
<div id="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Reload", "DateOfFile", FormMethod.Post, new { returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl, id = "formDate" }))
    {
       @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
          .Name("DateOfFile")
          .Value(Session["DateOfFile"] == null ? DateTime.Now : Convert.ToDateTime(Session["DateOfFile"].ToString()))
          .Events(e => e
          .Change("dt_picker_change")
          )
        )
          @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", this.Request.RawUrl)

           <script>
                function dt_picker_change() {
                    $("#container").kendoValidator({
                       rules: {
                          dateValidator: function (input) {
                          var value = $(input).val();
                          var date = kendo.parseDate(value);
                          //alert(date)
                          if (!date) {
                              return false;
                          }
                          $("#formDate").submit();
                       }
                    }); 
                }
           </script>
     }
</div>
```

In the code above, the form only submitted when I click somewhere outside the DatePicker control, but it need to submit as soon as the date is changed in calendar.

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems like it's working as expected, the change event on any text input will only fire when focus is lost.  You'll probably have to make your own event based on the calendar click or something.  Seems very messy, so you might want to reconsider this requirement.

Comment: @gene did u try the solution below? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set **validateOnBlur: false** on your validator and to validate the input on change event?

```
<div id="container">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Reload", "DateOfFile", FormMethod.Post, new { returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl, id = "formDate" }))
        {
           @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
              .Name("DateOfFile")
              .Value(Session["DateOfFile"] == null ? DateTime.Now : Convert.ToDateTime(Session["DateOfFile"].ToString()))
              .Events(e => e
              .Change("dt_picker_change")
              )
            )
              @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", this.Request.RawUrl)

               <script>
                    function dt_picker_change() {
                       $("#container").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator").validate();
                    }

                    $("#container").kendoValidator({
                           validateOnBlur: false,
                           rules: {
                              dateValidator: function (input) {
                              var value = $(input).val();
                              var date = kendo.parseDate(value);


                              //alert(date)
                              if (!date) {
                                  return false;
                              }
                              $("#formDate").submit();
                           }
                        }); 

               </script>
         }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to take your whole "script" block of code and place it OUTSIDE your "div='container'".